# Login user into laravel using pin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

I have a very simple application of scoreboard in which I send an email to the users with the link. which looks like : `http://localhost:8888/users/evqGeyCgo4tIG2C` for now. here the string after `/users/` is a unique pin that is generated and emailed to the user.

So user simply clicks on the link and in the background I am trying to retrieve email and password of the user and attempt to login. But unfortunately, I cant use hashed password stored in Database to login.

This is my code :

Way 1 :

```
$user = User::select('email','password')->where('pin',$pin)->first();

        if (Auth::login($user)) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('/user');
        }
```

Way 2 :

```
$user = User::select('email','password')->where('pin',$pin)->first();

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $user->password])) {
            // Authentication passed...
            return redirect()->intended('/user');
        }
```

Unfortunately second way fails as I cant use the hashed password. And the first way I looked it from here but I dont see redirect to trigger. from here : https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#manually

I dont mind any other way/method to get the user loggedin with a pin. And I dont mind if any one user sees some other users profile.

So you might be thinking the pin is passed in url can be used by other user to login too. But I am not worried about it. Its just scores that users see of their game.

Comment: what do you mean cannot use the hashed password? Also what version of laravel as that link points to 4.2 and we are up to 5.2? and the redirect code in way 2 looks like laravel 5 code not 4.2??

Comment: Ya, I am using laravel 5.2 and I want to simply access the users password to make him/her loggedin. So if I login using $user->password. I get that long hashed password which would lead to fail attempt in loggin-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to log users in by their ID:

```
$user = User::select('id')->where('pin',$pin)->first();
Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
return redirect()->intended('/user');
```

Comment: Okay, Thanks it worked. But a small fix from my side. $user = User::select('id')->where('pin',$pin)->first(); Will accept an answer in a while

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, I would do something like this

```
// based on the fact that you have a Request object
$user = User::where('email', $request->input('email'))
        ->where('password', \Hash::make($request->input('password')))
        ->where('pin', $request->input('pin'))
        ->first();

if(! $user) {
    // you do not have a user that was found, so return some error
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors('Invalid user');
}

// since everything is good, just log the user in
Auth::login($user);

// redirect
return redirect()->route('whatever');
```

Comment: the problem here is he's using a link with just pin id, no form input?

Comment: user isnt inputting anything. but a pin. which I am using to retrieve the email and password. I guess you haven't understood my question. I need to login without email and password inputs. All I have is a pin.

Comment: So if you are just using a pin you can just base you query on that.

Comment: Sorry, comments :\  $user = User::where('pin', $pin)->first();   and the rest of the checks.. then just use Auth::login($user); if everything is right.  does that work based on the information you just put there?